# pandas to append result into csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, append, export-to-csv

I'm trying to append the result of the function to csv file, but the result is getting overwritten and i am only getting the value of last file in the csv.
My code is  something like this :

```
def Read (indir= "C:/Users/SSA/Desktop/New folder",outfile= "C:/Users/SSA/Desktop/final.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList= glob.glob("*.csv")
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename)

        ......



        y = df3.iloc[:,15].max()
        z= df3.iloc[:,15].min()
        x = Total_Time - Utilisation_time
        f = x / len(great)
        p = 6 * On_I

        df = pd.DataFrame({'Result':[y,z,x,f,p ]})

        df.to_csv(outfile, index = False)
        df.append('df', outfile)
```

When i am calling the function Read().
I get the csv file with values of only last file in the folder. its not getting appended!

Output: (which is the result of the last file only!!

```
filename
460.99
214.96
175.6663888889
0.0295237628
945.4583333333
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below logic, its simple, you can make it as a function as well.

```
path='path_of_folder'
list_of_files=os.listdir(path)

main_dat=pd.DataFrame()

for fil in list_of_files:
    ### do your stuff
    data=pd.read_csv(path+fil)
    ### do your stuff
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Result':[y,z,x,f,p ]})

    main_dat=pd.concat([main_dat,df])

main_dat.to_csv('save_your_output.csv',index=False) #your final result
```

PS:  you are using the 1st letter as capital for the function name, try to avoid also it should not be same as any inbuilt function name.